# Importing contacts to facebook from Google Apps account

Tags: facebook, google-workspace, import, google-contacts

I am using Google Apps for email on my domain.
I have many contacts in that account whom I would
like to invite to Facebook.

Is there a way other than importing all those contacts
to a Gmail account and then invite them?

I would like to invite them directly through my
Google apps account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log into you Google Apps E-mail
2. Click "Compose Mail"
3. Click "To:"
4. Select the contacts you want to invite, or click "All", then click done
5. Select all and copy everything in to to field
6. Go to http://www.facebook.com/invite.php
7. Paste into the "To:" Box
8. (Optional) Add a message for your friends
9. Click "Invite"

Facebook will correctly parse the list and send the invites! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Go to find Friends in Facebook, Then enter your Google email address and password in "Find people you email" Facebook will find all your Google contacts and send them an invite.

Comment: He's using Google Apps. Not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into your email on the web interface.
2. Click "Contacts."
3. Click the "export" link in the top right corner.
4. Select "Everyone" and choose the "Outlook CSV" format and click "Export."
5. Go to the [Facebook contact file import page](http://www.facebook.com/find-friends/?expand=upload).
6. Click "choose file" and select the CSV file you just got from Google.
7. Click "Find Friends."

I just tried it and got an unspecified error from Facebook, so you may need to see if the file is cleaned or not (or maybe Facebook is just acting up for me) but this is at least the start of a possible solution.